# Using rm(list=ls()) in a parallel environment in R

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing

I am running code in R that runs a function in parallel.  The code sets some parameters initially and loads libraries etc, then calls a function (called calibrate) and this runs across several workers using different input parameters on each worker in parallel and returns the result back to the centre.  It works, and a number of iterations take place (sometimes more than a 100 over a couple of hours) but crashes after a while, and I suspect that it is a memory resource issue.  Hence I want to include an rm type command to reduce memory usage:

At first the function looked like this:

```
Calibrate <- function() {
rm(list = ls())
gc()
...rest of code calling other functions
}
```

but this had very little effect.  When looking closely and running the code line by line I realised that rm(list=ls()) will do very little inside a function.

So, I thought I would change the code to:

```
Calibrate <- function() {
ENV <- globalenv()
ll <- ls(envir = ENV)
lf <- lsf.str(envir = ENV)
ll <- ll[ll != lf]
rm(list = ll, envir = ENV)
....rest of code calling other functions
}
```

This will now get rid of all the variables but not the functions.  However, I am worried that this will get rid of all the variables on all the other workers which will still be running.  The code runs in parallel but the code does not necessarily run on all the workers at the same speed.  So the code is effectively staggered.  I only want to remove the variables for an individual worker when the calibrate function is called.

So my question, what should I be doing to clear the variables (rm) for one worker and not the whole system when running in parallel?

Help, really appreciated.

Comment: No matter what the question is, `rm(list = ls())` is never the right answer. Avoid.

Comment: Avoided - fixed by adding type = "FORKS" when creating the cluster.